# For sentence of “She uses to her advantage” , why can a VT "use" accompany with a PP "to her advantage"?

Tags: prepositional-phrases

The original sentence is "she has this apparent innocence which, I suspect, she uses to her advantage."   (Cambridge Advanced Learners Dictionary, 4th).

I understand that "she has this apparent innocence" == Subject + transitive verb + Object;

"which" guide as an Attributive clause;

"I suspect" is a parenthesis;

However,  **I have a little confused with the sentence "she uses to her advantage"**,

Because "I" is a subject, "uses" is a transitive verb, **why can a transitive verb accompany with a prepositional phrase, "to her advantage"?**

I remember that the **transitive verb** **only accompanies with** one or more objects **such as** a Noun, a to-infinitive and some kinds of clauses **but not** a prepositional phrase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You yourself have said that *I suspect* is parenthetical, so you can remove that and not change the grammar of what’s left:

> she has this apparent innocence which she uses to her advantage.

I hope it’s clear now that *which* begins the relative clause *which she uses to her advantage*.

Put the *which* as the direct object of *uses*, as in

> she uses which to her advantage

And the *which* refers to *this apparent innocence*...

> she uses *this apparent innocence* to her advantage.

In short, the verb *use* can indeed govern a definite object and a prepositional phrase. It’s all about the verb. Many verbs can govern both an object and a prepositional phrase.

> He obeyed the law to his advantage.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed and clear explanation. It was very helpful and understandable.